# Wordpress admin area canonical url trouble

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm building a custom theme, with a custom post type. If I want to use the WordPress pager in the back end - to navigate between pages of posts - the URL it directs me to is wrong and I don't know where to even begin.

So the dev url is set up as

```
http://socor.dev
```

when I want to go to page 2 of the pages the URL should be:

```
http://socor.dev/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&paged=2
```

however the domain part of the URL is being stripped out and I'm left with:

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&paged=2
```

I noticed when looking through the front end code that this has been set:

```
<link id="wp-admin-canonical" rel="canonical"
      href="http:///wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&amp;paged=2">`
```

I am running the latest version of WordPress 4.5.1

Comment: Note that canonical is only useful for search engines and thus useless within the admin area since no search engine should be able to index those pages (they should get 401 or 403 errors).

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this, I've managed to work out what was going wrong.

I had managed to overwrite my domain name somewhere. I used:

```
var_dump($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']);
```

in my functions file to see what I had it set as.

It was weird because the admin area would load up fine in the first instance but would go through 404's and other errors when navigating through additional post pages.